# Sort array alphabetically, upper letter always first

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort arrays alphabetically but I want to have upper case letter always first. What I already achieved is a simple sort, which doesn't take to account size of letters. Shall I put a special condition for it?

**EDIT:**

This is what I want to achieve:
`AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI` should be sorted like this: `AAaaCcDdFfGgHhI`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2);

int main(void) {
    char s1[N][15] = {
        { "azghtdffopAsAfp" },
        { "poiuyjklhgADHTp" },
        { "hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk" },
        { "lokijuhygtfrdek" },
        { "AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI" } };

    char *wsk;
    int i, j;
    wsk = s1;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            printf("%c", s1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        qsort(s1[i], 15, sizeof(char), compare);

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            printf("%c", s1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {
    char *a1 = w1;
    char *a2 = w2;

    while (*a1 && *a2) {
        register r = tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
        if (r)
            return r;
        ++a1;
        ++a2;

    }
    return tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to sort 'upper case letters always first': "A", "a", "B", "b" or "A", "B", "a", "b" ?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: yes is not a valid answer to 'option 1 or option 2' :-)

Comment: BTW, your code does not compile. You by the least need to change the declaration of that `s1[N][15]` array.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt ah, sorry didnt saw it at the first glance. i Mean the first Option

Comment: @Buszman  Show what result you are  going to achieve.

Comment: @Buszman: I took the liberty of fixing the example's expected output: `AAaaCcDdFfGgHhI` instead of `AAaaCcDdFfGgHhi`.

Answer (score 2):

We should start by fixing a few issues in your code. First, you need to add `#include <ctype.h>`. You have declared `char *wsk;`, and assigned `wsk = s1;` for no apparent reason. More importantly, these are incompatible types, since `s1` is a pointer to an array of 15 `char`s. And more important still, `s1` *should* be an array of 16 `char`s! You have forgotten to include space for the `'\0'` terminator in your character arrays. So, the declaration of `s1` needs to become:

```
char s1[N][16] = { { "azghtdffopAsAfp" },
                   { "poiuyjklhgADHTp" },
                   { "hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk" },
                   { "lokijuhygtfrdek" },
                   { "AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI" } };
```

The call to `qsort()` can be improved. Rather than use the magic number `15`, it would be better to store the length of the strings in a variable. Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1:

```
for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    size_t s1_len = strlen(s1[i]);
    qsort(s1[i], s1_len, 1, compare);
}
```

In the `compare()` function itself, you need to change to:

```
const unsigned char *a1 = w1;
const unsigned char *a2 = w2;
```

The cast to `const` will avoid warnings about discarding `const` qualifiers. The cast to `unsigned` avoids undefined behavior since the `ctype.h` functions expect an `int` argument that is representable as an `unsigned char`, or equal to `EOF`. Also, `register` is a type *qualifier*: it needs to qualify a type. So you need `register int r = ...`.

But your function is also relying on a property of the encoding of the execution character set that is not guaranteed by the Standard: that the letters are encoded in alphabetic sequence. You have taken the first step towards portability by using the `tolower()` function, rather than adding magic numbers to change the case of the characters. By using `isupper()` and `islower()` to test the case of characters, and by using `strcoll()` to test the ordering of characters, we can achieve something approaching maximum portability. `strcoll()` automatically orders uppercase letters before lowercase if it is appropriate for the locale, but it appears that all uppercase letters precede the lowercase, so an explicit test will be necessary to order two characters that compare equal after conversion to lowercase. One obstacle to overcome is that `strcoll()` compares *strings* for lexical ordering. To use it to compare characters we can deploy compound literals:

```
register int r = strcoll((const char[]){tolower(*c1), '\0'},
                         (const char[]){tolower(*c2), '\0'});
```

There is a loop in your `compare()` function that makes no sense to me. The `compare()` function should just compare two `char`s; there is no need to loop through anything, so I have removed this loop.

I wrote a new `compare()` function that uses `strcoll()` and compound literals to portably compare two `char`s. If the two characters compare equal (up to case), then their cases are checked. If the cases differ, the uppercase character is taken to come before the lowercase character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>                 // added for strlen() and strcoll()
#include <ctype.h>                  // must add this

#define N 5

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2);

int main(void) {
    /* Inner dimension should be 16 to include '\0' */
    char s1[N][16] = { { "azghtdffopAsAfp" },
                       { "poiuyjklhgADHTp" },
                       { "hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk" },
                       { "lokijuhygtfrdek" },
                       { "AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI" } };

//    char *wsk;                    // don't need this
    int i, j;
//    wsk = s1;                     // don't need this, also incompatible

    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<15; j++) {
            printf("%c", s1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        size_t s1_len = strlen(s1[i]);
        qsort(s1[i], s1_len, 1, compare);  // improved call to qsort()
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<15; j++) {
            printf("%c", s1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *a1, const void *a2) {
    const unsigned char *c1 = a1;
    const unsigned char *c2 = a2;

    register int r = strcoll((const char[]){tolower(*c1), '\0'},
                             (const char[]){tolower(*c2), '\0'});
    if (r == 0) {
        if (isupper(*c1) && islower(*c2)) {
            r = -1;
        } else if (islower(*c1) && isupper(*c2)) {
            r = 1;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Program output:

```
azghtdffopAsAfp
poiuyjklhgADHTp
hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk
lokijuhygtfrdek
AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI

AAadfffghoppstz
ADgHhijkloppTuy
BFfGgghjKkknUuV
defghijkklortuy
AAaaCcDdFfGgHhI
```

Comment: Pedantic notes: 1) `while (*a1)` is sufficient.  2) Using `unsigned` as in `const unsigned char *a1 = w1;` matches `strcmp()` when negative valued `char` occur.  `tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2)` may overflow on rare platforms with wide `char`.

Comment: @chux-- Thanks for the notes. 1) On further examination, it appears to me that the loop is entirely superfluous. 2) This makes sense; it seems that overflow could occur even with the cast if `char` is as wide as `int`, yes? IAC, I have substantially expanded my answer, as I found other issues in OP's code. Instead of using subtraction, I rewrote `compare()` to use `strcoll()`. I believe that this obviates the need to cast to `unsigned`, and ensures maximum portability (or close to it). I would appreciate any further observations, though.

Comment: @Buszman- I have substantially expanded my answer; you may be interested in reading it to find a more portable solution.

Comment: BTW: a good improvement to notice that the loop is not needed. " believe that this obviates the need to cast to unsigned" --> no in general, but yes in OP's limited case.  With `const char *c1 = a1;`, `tolower(*c1)` is UB then `*c1` is negative   "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char`".  §7.23.1 3

Comment: @chux-- don't mean to bother, but I think that relevant section for `tolower()` is §7.4 1: "...value... shall be representable as an **unsigned char**..." I think that you were pointing to §7.24.1 3, which is about the string handling functions. This is relevant for `strcoll()`; there is no need to cast to `unsigned char` before giving characters (in the form of a string) to `strcoll()` though, correct? i.e., "representable as" vs. "interpreted as".

Comment: Yes my cite was in erroneous.  Your improved post does not  now call `tolower()` in a corner UB case.

Answer (score 1):

It is horribly unclear whether you want to sort all the characters in each ROW, or you want to sort the array of strings in the array, (or both). Both can be accomplished, but both have slightly different `compare` requirements.

Presuming you want to sort the array of arrays (easier if you make them strings), you would expect output like:

```
$ ./bin/sortcapsfirst
azghtdffopAsAfp
poiuyjklhgADHTp
hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk
lokijuhygtfrdek
AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI

AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI
azghtdffopAsAfp
hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk
lokijuhygtfrdek
poiuyjklhgADHTp
```

Otherwise, you would need to sort each row first (sorting each upper-case, before the same lower-case), then sort the array. That would result in output as follows:

```
$ ./bin/sortcapsfirst
azghtdffopAsAfp
poiuyjklhgADHTp
hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk
lokijuhygtfrdek
AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI

AAaaCcDdFfGgHhI
AAadfffghoppstz
ADgHhijkloppTuy
BFfGgghjKkknUuV
defghijkklortuy
```

You may be making things a bit harder on yourself than it needs to be. Generally, the natural string sort for your `LOCALE` will sort *Caps* first by default. In the case of sorting the array `s1` ordering the rows so that capitals sort before lower-case, you need only make your number of columns `16` (to provide space for a *nul-terminating* character) and then call `strcmp` in your `compare` routine, e.g.:

```
int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {

    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    return strcmp (a1, a2);
}
```

Putting it all together in an example, and properly terminating each `j` loop when the *nul-terminating* char is encountered, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 5
#define R 16

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2);

int main(void) {

    char s1[][R] = {{ "azghtdffopAsAfp" },
                    { "poiuyjklhgADHTp" },
                    { "hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk" },
                    { "lokijuhygtfrdek" },
                    { "AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI" }};
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[i][j] && j<R; j++) {
            putchar(s1[i][j]);  /* don't use printf to print a single-char */
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    qsort (s1, N, sizeof *s1, compare);  /* sort array (rows) */

    putchar('\n');
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[i][j] && j<R; j++) {
            putchar(s1[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {

    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    return strcmp (a1, a2);
}
```

For the second case where you sort the upper-case in each row before the equivalent lower-case and then sort the array, you simply add a second `qsort` compare function and call that as you are, before calling `qsort` on the entire array. e.g. (to sort each upper-case before the corresponding lower-case):

```
int compare (const void *w1, const void *w2) {
    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    while (*a1 && *a2)
    {
        int r = tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
        if (!r) {
            if (*a1 - *a2)
                return *a1 - *a2 > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else
            break;
        ++a1;
        ++a2;
    }
    // return *a1 - *a2; /* to sort ALLcapsfirst */
    return tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
}
```

Then call `qsort` as done in the first example to sort the rows in the array:

```
int comparestr (const void *w1, const void *w2) {

    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    return strcmp (a1, a2);
}
```

Putting that together in the same example (with *nul-terminated* rows), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 5
#define R 16

int compare (const void *w1, const void *w2);
int comparestr (const void *w1, const void *w2);

int main (void) {

    char s1[][R] = {{"azghtdffopAsAfp"},
                    {"poiuyjklhgADHTp"},
                    {"hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk"},
                    {"lokijuhygtfrdek"},
                    {"AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI"}};
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[i][j] && j < R; j++)
            putchar(s1[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)                     /* sort arrays */
        qsort (s1[i], R - 1, sizeof *(s1[i]), compare);
    qsort (s1, N, sizeof *s1, comparestr);      /* sort array */

    putchar('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[i][j] && j < R; j++)
            putchar(s1[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare (const void *w1, const void *w2)
{
    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    while (*a1 && *a2) {
        int r = tolower (*a1) - tolower (*a2);
        if (!r) {
            if (*a1 - *a2)
                return *a1 - *a2 > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        } else
            break;
        ++a1;
        ++a2;

    }
    // return *a1 - *a2; /* to sort ALLcapsfirst */
    return tolower (*a1) - tolower (*a2);
}

int comparestr (const void *w1, const void *w2)
{
    const char *a1 = w1;
    const char *a2 = w2;

    return strcmp (a1, a2);
}
```

Finally, as noted above, if you want to sort **ALLCapsfirst**, then simply return the difference between `*a1 - *a2` instead of `tolower (*a1) - tolower (*a2)`. e.g. using `return *a1 - *a2;` the sort would be:

```
AACDFGHIaacdfgh
AAadfffghoppstz
ADHTghijkloppuy
BFGKUVfgghjkknu
defghijkklortuy
```

Look things over. I could have misunderstood your goal completely. If so, drop a note and I can help further in a bit.

Comment: I don't see where the `comparestr()` function is used. I thought that it was meant to sort the strings after the characters of each string had been put in order, but you use `compare()` for this too. Interesting: I had thought that relying on the locale to sort uppercase before lowercase would work, but it seems that this results in _all_ uppercase preceding all lowercase, so I reverted in my answer. I mention this because as it is, this code works as OP expects because of `compare()`, but if `comparestr()` is used instead for the second sort, all capitalized strings precede noncapitalized.

Comment: No, no tricks, that was just an oversight on my part -- good catch. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the lowercase values, check the values ASCII values. In the table capital letters come first, then the lowercase ones: 
http://www.asciitable.com/

UPDATE: If you need a bit more platform and character set independent code, just add an extra `if`,  and check the letter case with `isupper()` and/or `islower()`:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_islower.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isupper.htm

Comment: Assuming ASCII is not portable. C Standard makes almost no restrictions on execution character set encoding.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want ABCDabbcd but AaBbCcDd

Answer (score 0):

if you want such that upper case lower case distiction is made per character, so you would sort like "A", "Aa", "AB", "aa", "B", "b", compare could look like that

```
int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {
    char *a1 = w1;
    char *a2 = w2;

    while (*a1 && *a2)
    {   
        register r = tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
        if (r)
            return r;
        // this is the new part
        else if( isupper( *a1 ) && !isupper( *a2 ) ) {
            // w1 < w2
            return -1;
        } else if( !isupper( *a1 ) && isupper( *a2 ) ) {
            // w1 > w2
            return 1;
        }

        ++a1;
        ++a2;

    }
    return tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
```

}

If you want "aa" to be sorted *before* "AB" it could look like:

```
int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {
    char *a1 = w1;
    char *a2 = w2;
    register r;
    int caseDifference = 0;

    while (*a1 && *a2)
    {   
        r = tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
        if (r)
            return r;
        // this is the new part
        else if( caseDifference == 0 && ( isupper( *a1 ) && !isupper( *a2 ) ) ) {
            // w1 < w2
            caseDifference = -1;
        } else if( caseDifference == 0 && ( !isupper( *a1 ) && isupper( *a2 ) ) ) {
            // w1 > w2
            caseDifference = 1;
        }

        ++a1;
        ++a2;

    }
    r = tolower(*a1) - tolower(*a2);
    if( r != 0 )
        return r;
    else
        return caseDifference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function is incorrect: it compares multiple characters instead of just the ones pointed to by the arguments.

If you can assume ASCII, here is a much simpler comparison function that solves the problem:

```
int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2) {
    int c1 = *(const unsigned char *)w1;
    int c2 = *(const unsigned char *)w2;
    int l1 = tolower(c1);
    int l2 = tolower(c2);

    /* sort first by alphabetical character, then by case */
    return l1 != l2 ? l1 - l2 : c1 - c2;
}
```

Also note that the `main()` function can be simplified too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

int compare(const void *w1, const void *w2);

int main(void) {
    char s1[N][15] = {
        { "azghtdffopAsAfp" },
        { "poiuyjklhgADHTp" },
        { "hgjkFfGgBnVUuKk" },
        { "lokijuhygtfrdek" },
        { "AaaAdDcCFfgGhHI" } };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%.15s\n", s1[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        qsort(s1[i], 15, sizeof(char), compare);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%.15s\n", s1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```